# Parsing values from JSON using php

Tags: php, json

I'm new to PHP and JSON, so hoping someone can help me.

I have a PHP which a 3rd party performs a POST against, delivering JSON data. An example of the data sent would be:

```
> {   "created": 1326853478,   "livemode": false,   "id":
> "evt_00000000000000",   "type": "charge.succeeded",   "object":
> "event",   "data": {
>     "object": {
>       "id": "ch_00000000000000",
>       "object": "charge",
>       "created": 1366838716,
>       "livemode": false,
>       "paid": true,
>       "amount": 1000,
>       "currency": "gbp",
>       "refunded": false,
>       "fee": 59,
>       "fee_details": [
>         {
>           "amount": 59,
>           "currency": "usd",
>           "type": "stripe_fee",
>           "description": "Stripe processing fees",
>           "application": null,
>           "amount_refunded": 0
>         }
>       ],
>       "card": {
>         "object": "card",
>         "last4": "4242",
>         "type": "Visa",
>         "exp_month": 2,
>         "exp_year": 2016,
>         "fingerprint": "cniJDyeew54ashW6Iyr",
>         "country": "US",
>         "name": "wibble3",
>         "address_line1": null,
>         "address_line2": null,
>         "address_city": null,
>         "address_state": null,
>         "address_zip": null,
>         "address_country": null,
>         "cvc_check": "pass",
>         "address_line1_check": null,
>         "address_zip_check": null
>       },
>       "captured": true,
>       "failure_message": null,
>       "amount_refunded": 0,
>       "customer": null,
>       "invoice": null,
>       "description": null,
>       "dispute": null
>     }   } }
```

I would like to be able to extract certain items to then process depending on these values.

Using this code, I can extract the 'type' easily enough:

```
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);
print $event_json->{'type'};
```

But I cannot extract "fee" for example, which seems to be a level below where I am successfully extracting a value from, or "description" which is another level down again.

I would like to be able to extract only certain items from this JSON string (for example, Type, Fee, Description, Last4), but I am completely lost. I appreciate this is likely a fairly basic task, but I'm getting no where.

Any help, gratefully received!

Comment: Have you tried calling json_last_error() after your call to json_decode to make sure everything is being read properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest passing `true` as the second argument to `json_decode`. This results in an associative array rather than an object, which makes it a little easier to work with.

Then, you can do this:

```
$fee = $event_json['data']['object']['fee'];
```

You can chain these square brackets as many times as needed to delve deeper into the array.

Answer (score 2):

You can quickly acheive this in following manner:

```
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body, true);
print $event_json['data']['object']['fee'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you have multi levels of objects so use:

```
echo($event_json->data->object->fee);
```

Basically you are echoing `fee`, which is a member of the object name `object`, which in turn is the attribute of an object named `data`, which again in turn is a member of your `$event_json` object.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a json_decode, you get an array of this data. So, you can access data like this:

```
$event_json['data']['object']['fee']
```

good luck