# Sorting Wikipedia API search results into an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Using the following code as an example:

```
$wikisearch = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=inception";
$wikisearchlist = file_get_contents($wikisearch);
echo $wikisearchlist;
```

I get this:

```
[
    "inception",
    [
        "Inception",
        "Inception Motorsports",
        "Inception of Darwin's theory",
        "Inception (soundtrack)",
        "Inception (McCoy Tyner album)",
        "Inception (Download album)",
        "Inception/Nostalgia",
        "Inception date",
        "Inception (disambiguation)"
    ]
]
```

I want to firstly remove the query at the start ("inception"), then decode the JSON to create an array of all the results. Then, remove the array elements that don't contain '(soundtrack)' and '(Download album)' in them (except the first result), so the final array would look something like:

```
[0] => "Inception"
[1] => "Inception (soundtrack)"
[2] => "Inception (Download album)"
```

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, *"decode the JSON"*, eh? If only there was a function that could do that? I wonder what it would be named?

Comment: There's more to do after that though

Comment: Oh right. If only there was a way to *filter* an *array*. I wonder what that function would be called?

Comment: BTW, what have you tried? Where are your attempted solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing values from JSON using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218621/parsing-values-from-json-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *Decode the JSON*

```
$json = json_decode($wikisearchlist);
$results = $json[1];
```

#### *Filter the array*

```
$first = array_shift($results);

$filtered = array_filter($results, function($result) {
    return strpos($result, '(soundtrack)') !== false
        || strpos($result, '(Download album)') !== false;
});

array_unshift($filtered, $first);
```

Demo here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/siX4aY